# How to return a new object with little modification in C#?

Tags: c#, function, oop, immutability

Hello I would like to ask about this code:

Edit: The class is immutable, I make it auto-property instead of private.

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Title { get; }
    public int Age { get; }
    public Image Picture { get; }

    .... // lot of other fields

    private string Address { get; }

    public Person(int id, string name, ...) {
    // usual constructor init
    }
}

var John = new Person(1, "John", "Mr.", 54, ... );
```

Now I would like to create a new person (without mutation) based on John, only small modification on some fields, such as name and age.

In Javascript I could do something like this:

```
let bob = Object.assign({}, john, {name: "bob", age: 55};
```

How to return a new object with little modification in C#?

```
// something like this?
var Bob = Person.From(John, name: "Bob", age: 55);
```

Comment: Have a look at the examples and remarks here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects
Possible you want to know how to deep clone a object in C#

Comment: I don't think the "duplicate" answer actually answers the question. OP doesn't want to clone the object, he wants to make a copy with one or two properties changed. After cloning the object, he's still left with the same problem - and it looks like this is an immutable class, so he can't just mutate the properties in the clone.

Comment: `Record` types have been proposed for C# (but they are still at the proposal stage). If/when they are implemented, you could write code like `var john = person with {name: "Bob", age: 55};` - but that's probably C#9 or later, if ever!

Comment: [This article about implementing "With" semantics in C#](https://www.productiverage.com/implementing-f-sharp-inspired-with-updates-for-immutable-classes-in-c-sharp) might be of interest.

Comment: oh very nice, I'm pretty sure that "with" will do exactly what I wanted, sadly that one is not implemented yet in c#, Shallow/ Deep Copy doesn't look like a solution, I still need to change some fields.. and field with reference type should not be shared between John and Bob

Comment: @KevinTanudjaja if you want a copy, but change name and age, if doing `bob.Title = "Sir";` should change `john.Title` too ?

Comment: @Cid , hello, John should be immutable type, John title should be "Mr" until he got garbage collected.